# Fresh svn checkout taking old revision files

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven, jenkins

1. I created a new branch from trunk (all are Java projects)
2. I changed pom.xml file and committed 4 times after
3. In Jenkins job I specified new branch svn URL instead of trunk.
4. I run the job.
5. I find the pom.xml it is taking from old revision(2nd revision in 4) instead of latest.
6. I check the pom.xml svn history from Eclipse, it is showing some **star mark** at the 2nd revision number.

I don't know why it came like that, how can I resolve it?

Comment: Where did you change pom.xml? In the branch, or in the trunk?

Comment: Are you sure that your workspace is currently on the branch ?